# Complex algorithm to extract numbers/number range from a string

Tags: c++, c, string, strtok, strtol

I am working on a algorithm where I am trying the following output:

Given values/Inputs:

`char *Var = "1-5,10,12,15-16,25-35,67,69,99-105";`
`int size  = 29;`

Here *"1-5"* depicts a range value, i.e. it will be understood as *"1,2,3,4,5"* while the values with just **","** are individual values.

I was writing an algorithm where end output should be such that it will give complete range of output as:

```
int list[]=1,2,3,4,5,10,12,15,16,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,67,69,99,100,101,102,103,104,105;
```

If anyone is familiar with this issue then the help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

My initial code approach was as:

```
if(NULL != strchr((char *)grp_range, '-'))
{
    int_u8 delims[] = "-";
    result = (int_u8 *)strtok((char *)grp_range, (char *)delims);

    if(NULL != result)
    {
        start_index = strtol((char*)result, (char **)&end_ptr, 10);
        result = (int_u8 *)strtok(NULL, (char *)delims);
    }

    while(NULL != result)
    {
        end_index = strtol((char*)result, (char**)&end_ptr, 10);
        result = (int_u8 *)strtok(NULL, (char *)delims);
    }

    while(start_index <= end_index)
    {
        grp_list[i++] = start_index;
        start_index++;
    }
}

else if(NULL != strchr((char *)grp_range, ','))
{
    int_u8 delims[] = ",";
    result = (unison_u8 *)strtok((char *)grp_range, (char *)delims);

    while(result != NULL)
    {
        grp_list[i++] = strtol((char*)result, (char**)&end_ptr, 10);
        result = (int_u8 *)strtok(NULL, (char *)delims);
    }
}
```

But it only works if I have either "0-5" or "0,10,15". I am looking forward to make it more versatile.

Comment: Yes! I have tried it myself but the logic seems too complex.

Comment: Never use a non-const `char *` to point to a string literal. And is this C or C++? The answers will be wildly different.

Comment: _"Yes!"_  First show reasonable code/approaches

Comment: @chris Thanks for the input. But could you plz see if you can come up with an algo for this? It is quite complex.

Comment: Do you have access to a good regex implementation? If so, it's trivial. (Edit) Actually, straightforward decoding is not "hard" either. Just start at the beginning.

Comment: My god, it's full of stars!

Comment: @LetsCode Break the problem down into simpler tasks until you can solve it.

Comment: @P0W there you go. HAve a look at my initial approach

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers! There are many correct answers, but I ll accept the one suitable for me. Pardon my rude answers yesterday, ofcourse there are so many brilliant minds here. Thanks again! @AndrewBarber

Comment: Glad you got good info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're issue seems to be misunderstanding how strtok works.  Have a look at this.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int i, j;
        char delims[] = " ,";
        char str[] = "1-5,6,7";
        char *tok;
        char tmp[256];
        int rstart, rend;

        tok = strtok(str, delims);

        while(tok != NULL) {
                for(i = 0; i < strlen(tok); ++i) {
                        //// range
                        if(i != 0 && tok[i] == '-') {
                                strncpy(tmp, tok, i); 
                                rstart = atoi(tmp);
                                strcpy(tmp, tok + i + 1); 
                                rend = atoi(tmp);
                                for(j = rstart; j <= rend; ++j)
                                        printf("%d\n", j); 
                                i = strlen(tok) + 1;
                        }   
                        else if(strchr(tok, '-') == NULL)
                                printf("%s\n", tok);
                }   

                tok = strtok(NULL, delims);
        }   

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This exact example will crash, of course.  `strtok`: just say no.

Comment: Then your compiler is doing something unusual.  (I know that Sun CC does, for various historical reasons.)  The type of `"1-5,6,7"` is `char const[]`, and most compilers will put it in write protected memory.

Comment: You were right, I had to change it from char *var to char var[].  See my above edit, when I originally tried I didn't seem to get a segfault.  Once I wrote the full solution it failed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a C++ solution for you to study.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ConvertString2Int(const string& str)
{
    stringstream ss(str);
    int x;
    if (! (ss >> x))
    {
        cerr << "Error converting " << str << " to integer" << endl;
        abort();
    }
    return x;
}

vector<string> SplitStringToArray(const string& str, char splitter)
{
    vector<string> tokens;
    stringstream ss(str);
    string temp;
    while (getline(ss, temp, splitter)) // split into new "lines" based on character
    {
        tokens.push_back(temp);
    }
    return tokens;
}

vector<int> ParseData(const string& data)
{
    vector<string> tokens = SplitStringToArray(data, ',');

    vector<int> result;
    for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = tokens.begin(), end_it = tokens.end(); it != end_it; ++it)
    {
        const string& token = *it;
        vector<string> range = SplitStringToArray(token, '-');
        if (range.size() == 1)
        {
            result.push_back(ConvertString2Int(range[0]));
        }
        else if (range.size() == 2)
        {
            int start = ConvertString2Int(range[0]);
            int stop = ConvertString2Int(range[1]);
            for (int i = start; i <= stop; i++)
            {
                result.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cerr << "Error parsing token " << token << endl;
            abort();
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> result = ParseData("1-5,10,12,15-16,25-35,67,69,99-105");
    for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = result.begin(), end_it = result.end(); it != end_it; ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Live example

http://ideone.com/2W99Tt

Comment: Wow! well done mate. Thanks, let me convert it to C and check.

Comment: @LetsCode Why would you want to convert it to C? Your question was tagged C++

Comment: @LetsCode Well have fun with that. If you try converting that you’ll see that C and C++ are nothing alike.

Comment: That's a lot of lines of code for a very simple problem (but the basic approach is good).

Comment: @JamesKanze Some of the code may be reused as helpful utility functions. But how would you make it shorter?

Comment: @NeilKirk By keeping everything in a single `std::istringstream`, and passing a reference to that around, for starters.  (Or inversely, by just using `std::string::const_iterator` pairs everywhere, and only converting to `std::istringstream` for the numerical conversion.)  By treating the single number and range forms identically.  But part of what gave me the impression that there were a lot of lines was the fact that you actually gave a complete program, with includes and everything.  It's actually a pretty good solution.

Comment: @NeilKirk And now for the nits: if one of the fields is `"1abc"`, you won't generate an error.  In `ConvertStringToInt`, you need to add a `>> std::ws` and verify that after than, `ss.get()` returns end of file.  (And you really should be using `std::istringstream`, and not `std::stringstream`.)

Comment: @NeilKirk And an even nittier nit: Your naming convention is inconsistent: `ConvertString2Int`, but `SplitStringToArray`.  (Of course, personally, I don't like repeating information that is directly visible in the signature.  `convertToInt`, or simply `toInt`, and `split` are fine.  The longer forms that you use are a holdover from C, where you needed different names for different types.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, you're right. I must've mistaken Cpp & C similarity. Both are quite different.

Comment: @NeilKirk Thanks for your effort. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

This is my boost approach :

This won't give you array of ints, instead a vector of ints

Algorithm used: (nothing new)

- Split string using `,`
- Split the individual string using `-`
- Make a range `low` and `high`
- Push it into vector with help of this range

Code:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>


int main(){

    std::string line("1-5,10,12,15-16,25-35,67,69,99-105");
    std::vector<std::string> strs,r;
    std::vector<int> v;
    int low,high,i;
    boost::split(strs,line,boost::is_any_of(","));

for (auto it:strs)
{
    boost::split(r,it,boost::is_any_of("-"));

    auto x = r.begin();
    low = high =boost::lexical_cast<int>(r[0]);
    x++;
    if(x!=r.end())
        high = boost::lexical_cast<int>(r[1]);
    for(i=low;i<=high;++i)
      v.push_back(i);
}

for(auto x:v)
  std::cout<<x<<" ";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: That's probably the solution I'd actually use.  But then, I've had the equivalent of `boost::split` in my tool kit for ages (long before there was Boost).  It makes the problem too simple.

Comment: Beautiful job with my issue! Thanks for your effort. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Don't search. Just go through the text one character at a time. As long as you're seeing digits, accumulate them into a value. If the digits are followed by a `-` then you're looking at a range, and need to parse the next set of digits to get the upper bound of the range and put all the values into your list. If the value is not followed by a `-` then you've got a single value; put it into your list.

Comment: Nice thought! That's what I need. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: That's actually an interesting solution.  Once you've got the first number, if the next character is a `-`, skip it and collect the second.  If it's not, make the range using the first number as both start and end point.  Either way, the higher level logic only sees a list of ranges.

Comment: Yes. This is a "stack-based" approach, where you only ever have to have one number on the stack -- the last whole number read. The next character defines what happens: `,` = push onto list, `-` = read next, push list, binary 0 = end.

Comment: I really liked your idea. It gave me inspiration to look at the problem in a simple way. Thanks for your effort. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Stop and think about it: what you actually have is a comma
separated list of ranges, where a range can be either a single
number, or a pair of numbers separated by a `'-'`.  So you
probably want to loop over the ranges, using recursive descent
for the parsing.  (This sort of thing is best handled by an
`istream`, so that's what I'll use.)

```
std::vector<int> results;
std::istringstream parser( std::string( var ) );
processRange( results, parser );
while ( isSeparator( parser, ',' ) ) {
    processRange( results, parser );
}
```

with:

```
bool
isSeparator( std::istream& source, char separ )
{
    char next;
    source >> next;
    if ( source && next != separ ) {
        source.putback( next );
    }
    return source && next == separ;
}
```

and

```
void
processRange( std::vector<int>& results, std::istream& source )
{
    int first = 0;
    source >> first;
    int last = first;
    if ( isSeparator( source, '-' ) ) {
        source >> last;
    }
    if ( last < first ) {
        source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
    } 
    if ( source ) {
        while ( first != last ) {
            results.push_back( first );
            ++ first;
        }
        results.push_back( first );
    }
}
```

The `isSeparator` function will, in fact, probably be useful in
other projects in the future, and should be kept in your
toolbox.

Comment: List of ranges with two different range specifiers is correct. For example, 10 really means 10-10.

Comment: @AdamBurry That's the way I would parse it.  Other solutions may also be valid.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

You need a parser that identifies 3 kinds of tokens: ',', '-', and numbers. That raises the level of abstraction so that you are operating at a level above characters.

Then you can parse your token stream to create a list of ranges and constants.

Then you can parse that list to convert the ranges into constants.

Some code that does part of the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Prints a comma after the last digit. You will need to fix that up.
void print(int a, int b) {
  for (int i = a; i <= b; ++i) {
    printf("%d, ", i);
  }
}

int main() {
  enum { DASH, COMMA, NUMBER };
  struct token {
    int type;
    int value;
  };

  // Sample input stream. Notice the sentinel comma at the end.
  // 1-5,10,
  struct token tokStream[] = {
    { NUMBER, 1 },
    { DASH, 0 },
    { NUMBER, 5 },
    { COMMA, 0 },
    { NUMBER, 10 },
    { COMMA, 0 } };

  // This parser assumes well formed input. You have to add all the error
  // checking yourself.
  size_t i = 0;
  while (i < sizeof(tokStream)/sizeof(struct token)) {
    if (tokStream[i+1].type == COMMA) {
      print(tokStream[i].value, tokStream[i].value);
      i += 2;  // skip to next number
    }
    else { // DASH
      print(tokStream[i].value, tokStream[i+2].value);
      i += 4;  // skip to next number
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's true that one could probably write a solution using lex and yacc in about 5 minutes.  It would probably be the simplest to understand and maintain, as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution works but I will have to give input in a struct which is not what i am looking for. Any thanks for your effort. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

First divide whole string into numbers and ranges (using strtok() with "," delimiter), save strings in array, then, search through array looking for "-", if it present than use sscanf() with "%d-%d" format, else use sscanf with single "%d" format.

Function usage is easily googling.

Comment: Do _not_ use `strtok`.  There are better ways, always.  In this case, in C, `strchr` would be a good choice.  An even better choice, of course, would be to use `std::string`, and the functions in the standard library.

Comment: I understand that strtok() breaks string, but it's a raw solution, without any improvements and good tools. Meanwhile better solution has already written.